# Spark: Shuffle with Parallelism = 1

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am running `Spark` on only one node with `Parallelism = 1` in order to compare its performance with a single-threaded application. I'm wondering if `Spark` is still using a `Shuffle` although it does not run in parallel. So if e.g. the following command is executed:

```scala
val counts = text_file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
   .map(word => (word, 1))
   .reduceByKey(_+_)
```

I get the following output from the Spark Interactive Scala Shell:

```
counts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[10] 
                                                  at reduceByKey at <console>:41
```

So should I assume, that a `Shuffle` was used before `reduceByKey`? And does `[10]` actually has any meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if Spark is still using a Shuffle although it does not run in parallel.

Yes it does. It is worth noting that even with a single core number of partitions may be much larger than one. For example if RDD is created using `SparkContext.textFile` number of partitions depends on a size of the file system block.

> So should I assume, that a Shuffle was used before reduceByKey

No, shuffle is a fundamental part of the `reduceByKey` logic so it was used during `reduceByKey`, not before. Simplifying things a little bit `shuffle` is an equivalent of creating a hash table. Assuming only a single partition it doesn't perform any useful task but is still present.

> And does [10] actually has any meaning?

It is a unique (in the current `SparkContext`) ID for a given RDD. For example if RDD is persisted then the number you see should be a key in `SparkContext.getPersistentRDDs`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This helps a lot. You are writing " `shuffle` is an equivalent of creating a hash table ". Does Spark use `hashing` when shuffling? I thought it uses `sorting`..

Comment: Ok, I checked in the configuration description: spark uses `sort` by default but you can also choose `hash` or `tungsten-sort` for the `spark.shuffle.manager`.

Comment: It is not exactly what I mean. Shuffling is required to create a relationship between key and the partition which holds it.